# Adobe Reader could not open 'StreamTest5.pdf' because it is either not a supported file or file has been damaged error

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, filestream

I am trying to create a pdf file using file stream and while the file is being created in the specified folder of the path, when I try to open the file Adobe Reader is throwing the error that I mentioned above in the title. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I would greatly appreciate it if someone could look into it and help me out. Thank you!. Here is my code for the filestream:

```
            System.IO.FileStream wFile;
            byte[] byteData = null;
            byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("FileStream Test");
            string filePath = $"{_ApplicationPath}PrintedResults\\StreamTest5.pdf";
            wFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            wFile.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            wFile.Close();
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("This is a test stream file");

            }
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are writing a text file with the contents "FileStream Test" but naming it with a file extension of ".PDF".  This is not a PDF file.  It is a text file with a misleading name.  Adobe Reader is correctly reporting that it is not a valid PDF.

Comment: Could you help me out with the code for writing a pdf file rather than the text?

Comment: You will need a 3rd party library to generate a PDF, or spend a lot of time researching the PDF format itself and try to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but I don't have enough reputation to add it as a comment:

You might want to look to 3rd party library offered by http://www.dynamicpdf.com/
Their free evaluation version is quite capable and it is not time limited as they say on their website. With a little more effort you can create quite complicated PDFs with only the evaluation version!